# Is there a way to use JMS in a JUnit test?

Tags: java, junit, jboss, jms, cdi

I want to run a JUnit test with usage of JMS. Is it possible to have a JUnit test use JMS outside of an Application Server like JBoss or a CDI container?

Comment: why the down vote?  this is a reasonable question

Comment: @chrisl08 answer is good. Alternatively you can use an **embedded broker** to avoid mocking. This way you can test the integration between your components/ classes without any stubs or mocks. It's closer to a real life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that sending and consuming the message is completely decoupled from JMS, you could mock it.

For example: You can have a class that implements an interface like "IMyClassSender". In real code (non junit), all this class does is submit the message to JMS.  In junit, implement IMyClassSender with a class that takes the input and instead if submitting to JMS, it passes it to your consumer class.

Alternatively, if you are using active mq: http://activemq.apache.org/how-to-unit-test-jms-code.html

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution! Mocking JMS! A question about activemq, I would need to include the activemq library into the project to use it in the JUnit?

Comment: Also with ActiveMQ, wouldn't I need the ActiveMQ server to be running?

Comment: Not really, because you can use `EmbeddedActiveMQBroker` - see the link provided in the answer for the details.

Comment: to be honest, I have never used the method described in the link above. We always use the "mock" method. I just offered it as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

You may also reconsider using an application server for this - Arquillian (http://arquillian.org) allows for executing unit and integration test within a JavaEE environment of your choice - and manages the app server lifecycle on its own.

Comment: Yes, your answer is valuable, but Arquillian has its nuances. Its setup is quite complex, its nature is focused on creating "micro deployments" for each test, tests execution is quite long and so on...

Comment: plus, the question did state clearly " JUnit test use JMS outside of an Application Server"

Comment: There is also a known problem with Arquillian not releasing resources after a test completes. This problem can be a showstopper when you plan to run your tests in a Continuous Deployment environment such as Jenkins.